# Visited link on the main page has a confusing coloring

Tags: feature-request, design

> [image]

In my example, green circles are put around those links which I didn't visit; visited links I circled with red. As you see, in the visited link only "modified" is colored, while the whole "modified X [secs/mins/hrs] ago USER_NAME" is a link.

I think the whole visited link should be colored with the different color, probably not blue, so as not to, again, confuse with another link - user name.

Comment: What is so confusing?  To be honest, I don't notice little things like colour coordination etc

Comment: @Sab looks like only "modified" is a link if it has different colouring comparing to its timestamp

Comment: I never noticed, I just look at the words.